# Font quality in adjacent pages in wkhtmltopdf

Tags: html, pdf, wkhtmltopdf

I'm trying to convert pretty big HTML document to PDF through `wkhtmltopdf`. It splits my document into pages good enough, but the problem is that font quality in several adjacent pages differs too much.
For example, pages 2, 14, 45, 50 have very bad font quality and the rest of the pages are good.

Maybe there are some options I must use to get all pages of the same quality?

P.S. I'm printing with options `--no-background` and `--print-media-type`. Also I've tried `--disable-smart-shrinking` but got no result.

**EDIT**
I've noticed that this problem occurs in pages containing images.

Comment: Any example of a PDF or the source HTML so we could test and reproduce?

Comment: Try explicitly adding `font-style` or `font-family` styling to the text.